# What can saliva tell about ones health?

Tags: microbiology, pathology, enzymes, virus, saliva

I was wondering if I d want to analyze something related to my current health based on my saliva. What could it be?

I mean e.g. by putting a thermometer in your mouth you can know your body temperature and know whether your immune system is eventually fighting some disease. But as you already have that apparatus in your mouth I think it would be usefull to prelevate some saliva (hit two birds withone stone) or other stuff in order to eventually easily investigate ones health.

Comment: If there was broadly relevant information about one's health available by sampling saliva, tests would already have been developed. There are some *specific* assays that can be performed by analyzing saliva, such as looking for the presence of certain pathogens and proteins, but you won't be able to get anywhere near the broad-spectrum indicator of health (or disease) as you would be able to from a carefully-chosen panel of blood tests.

Comment: @MattDMo: Sex hormones analysis, for hormonal disorders specific to females and males by saliva tests. Correct?

Comment: there do exist tests for that, yes. And I mentioned that some clinical salivary tests exist in my above comment, but the point remains that the broad range of assays available for blood isn't even distantly approached by how many and what kind are available for saliva.

Answer (score 0):

Well, saliva (or the rate of production of saliva in your mouth) can tell you a lot about health, but the information you acquire is extremely general, so it won't really give you an entire health analysis in terms of diseases, sugar levels, body temperature, likewise.

As for what saliva does tell about your health, here is an extract from a source:

> "Dr. Stuart Froum, president of the American Academy of Periodontists, says: “If the eye is the window to the soul, the mouth is the window to the body.” Saliva in the mouth is one of the best indicators of health. If something is off, there is a good chance your saliva will change as a direct reflection.
>
> Saliva is produced around the clock and is affected not only by every bite of food you take, but also every other thing you put in your mouth. If you notice your saliva is too stringy or thick, your body might be having a hard time producing saliva. This could be because of the prescription and over-the-counter medication you are taking.
>
> Studies indicate that an imbalance of the ‘stress hormone’ cortisol in saliva points to emotional sensitivity to stressful situations...the measurement of cortisol in saliva is becoming increasingly acceptable as a screening test for hypercortisolism, such as depression, hypertension and diabetes.

Source: http://healthtoday.com/5-things-your-saliva-can-tell-you-about-your-health/
http://www.medicaldaily.com